# MinGW fails to compile library

Tags: c++, mingw

I'm trying to compile some library, however I run into trouble. My errors:

1)'size_t' does not name a type typedef size_t rsize_t;
2)'errno_t' does not name a type errno_t __cdecl _get_errno(int *_Value);
3)'uintptr_t' does not name a type
   _CRTIMP extern uintptr_t __cdecl __threadhandle(void);
4)'typedef wchar_t wctype_t' typedef wchar_t  wctype_t;

Really don't have a clue what's the problem behind. Any help is highly appreciated.

P.S more info:

I'm trying to compile [vmime](https://www.vmime.org/) on Windows. the code sections where error occured 
crtdefs.h

```
1)
:#ifndef _RSIZE_T_DEFINED
typedef size_t rsize_t;
#define _RSIZE_T_DEFINED
#endif

stddef.h    
2)
    #ifndef _CRT_ERRNO_DEFINED
    #define _CRT_ERRNO_DEFINED
      _CRTIMP extern int *__cdecl _errno(void);
    #define errno (*_errno())
      errno_t __cdecl _set_errno(int _Value);
      errno_t __cdecl _get_errno(int *_Value);
    #endif /* _CRT_ERRNO_DEFINED */

4)wctype.h 
      typedef wchar_t  wctype_t;
```

After Googling found out that this may happen when the cross-compiling mode switched on so the compiler include some headers for the other OS. Again -any help is higly appreciated.

Comment: Please tell us what library you are trying to compile. Just "some library" is not helpful enough to allow us to help you. You might also want to post the relevant code sections where the errors occur.

Comment: Yes,sure. thanks for answer! The question is updated above with more info

Comment: Does replacing `size_t` with `std::size_t` get rid of that error? If so, the project probably has a portability bug.

Comment: i've compiled the library with pure mingw (more recent version gcc 5.3.0) and these errors are gone, If you try to compile it with mingw, included with qt creator package(as i did) you may get these errors.